# Overwrite the write method

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, axapta, microsoft-dynamics

I would overwrite the Write method of the DS `LogisticsPostalAdress` form `DirPartyQuickCreateForm`.

But I have the following error:

> LogisticsPostalAddress write method if the data source property is ChangeGroupMode in ImplicitInnerOuter is not supported.

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

The DataSources node of your form has the property `ChangeGroupMode` set to `None`, default, or `ImplicitInnerOuter`, not default, but the form LogisticsPostalAdress has it set so.

If set to `None` the `write` method is available.
If set to `ImplicitInnerOuter` the `write` method is *not* available, but the methods `writing` and `written` are. The former is called before writing records and the latter is called after.

See [How To do Unit of work implementation for a Form](https://dynamicsaxposed.wordpress.com/tag/implicit-inner-outer/) for an informal explanation and [Change Group and Optional Record Modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj129662.aspx) for the formal.